# In Which ocean does Bhagwan Vishnu sleep?

Tags: vishnu

In the pictures of Bhagwan Vishnu, it is shown that he sleeps on Shesh-Naag, surrounded by some ocean.
I want to know which ocean it is ?

Where it is located ?

Comment: It's kṣīrasāgara. As per Bhāgavata Purāṇa (5.20.18), kṣīrasāgara surrounds the krauñcadvīpa. But as per Viṣṇu Purāṇa (2.4.71), it surrounds the śākadvīpa, which is strange as most other Purāṇas mention that kṣīrasāgara surrounds krauñcadvīpa. Anyway, kṣīrasāgara is not a sāgara which you can see or travel to by plane, ship, etc. It's none of the oceans we can see. So, we can't point its location on the maps we have, for we only have the maps of what we can see, perceive and travel to. In short, it's not the earth we know.

Comment: @Bingming Where is Krauncadvipa ? What does this word mean ?

Comment: It's a dvīpa named Krauñca, situated b/w ghṛtasāgara and kṣīrasāgara. Krauñca is one of the saptadvīpas in bhūmaṇḍala. And it's named after the mountain Krauñca, located on it.